# Conversion of an existing relational database (MySQL) into a graph database (OrientDB)

Tags: javascript, java, relational-database, orientdb, graph-databases

Given an existing relational database ( MySQL) , how to convert it into a graph database in orientDB using java/ JavaScript ?

Pardon me if the question is not clear, I'm new to the community. :)

Comment: Tagging javascript and Java doesn't make too much sense. These are two different programming languages. It's not clear what you are asking. Are you looking for a tool to convert the database (off topic on SO) or do you want to write a program to do so yourself ( a possible answer would too broad because there is nothing in your question which states a problem you've encountered doing so) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import a DB from MYSQL to OrientDB you can use Teleporter, is the new features of the latest version (2.2.0).

To use it follow this steps:

1. Copying `orientdb-teleporter-1.0.0.jar` into you `/plugins` folder;
2. Copying `oteleporter.bat` into you `/bin` folder;
3. Creating a new graphdb in MySQL (if it already exist go to point 4)
4. From the terminal, go to your `/bin` folder and run this command:

   `oteleporter.bat -jdriver mysql -jurl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/graphdb
   -juser root -jpasswd MyPassword -ourl plocal:C:/path/to/graphdb -s naive -nr java -v 2`
5. Run the `server.bat`;
6. Go to Orient Studio and you'll see your DB imported

Hope it helps,

Regards